# Set column value with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
UPDATE Users
SET GeneralPoint =(SELECT PostResult.AveragePoint  FROM Users 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT AVG(PostsLikes.PostPoint) AS AveragePoint , PostsLikes.ID_User 
            FROM PostsLikes,Users
            WHERE PostsLikes.ID_User = Users.Id
            GROUP BY PostsLikes.ID_User) PostResult
ON Users.Id = PostResult.ID_User)
```

Comment: This subquery return four element i want to write each of them to 'GeneralPoint' of every user.

Comment: So do you want all User records to have one specific value or are you trying to do a bulk `Update` with a `Select`?

Comment: Yes. I have 10 User in Users table. But i want to write to user's general point for only 4 user. Because this subquery return 4 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use join

```
 UPDATE u
 set  GeneralPoint =b.avg_val
 from  Users u join

(SELECT AVG(pl.PostPoint) avg_val,pl.ID_User
 FROM PostsLikes pl group by pl.ID_User
 ) b on u.Id=b.ID_User
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated  subquery :

```
UPDATE u
     SET u.GeneralPoint = (SELECT AVG(pl.PostPoint) FROM PostsLikes pl WHERE pl.ID_User = u.id )
FROM Users u;
```

Comment: I wrote like it. But this subquery return more value

Comment: @SamirH-evHemzeyev . . . Then you did not write it like this.  The correlated subquery returns exactly one row with one column.

Answer (score 0):

```
--This should update all the user columns with the subquery values
--This works as it joins the Users table on your subquery by Users.Id
--I added the Users.Id value to the initial sub-query so you can join on it for the update
UPDATE Users
SET GeneralPoint = x.AveragePoint
FROM Users AS u
INNER JOIN
(SELECT PostResult.AveragePoint, Users.Id  FROM Users 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT AVG(PostsLikes.PostPoint) AS AveragePoint , PostsLikes.ID_User 
            FROM PostsLikes,Users
            WHERE PostsLikes.ID_User = Users.Id
            GROUP BY PostsLikes.ID_User) PostResult
ON Users.Id = PostResult.ID_User) AS x
ON x.Id = u.Id
```

Reference to Update with a Select statement: ([How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server))